# Dynamically render dojo checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo

Why does a checkbox created using the javascript and placed in DOM Tree using `dojo.place()` render as an `input[type="text"]` instead of an `input[type="checkbox"]` element?

generated HTML code :

```
<input id="baseCalcRoundCustomized" 
name="hierarchicalRounding.baseCalcRoundCustomized" 
value="0" dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox" class="pcheckbox" 
onchange="checkValue(this.id)" unchecked />
```

Comment: Please provide the code you use for generating the checkbox. If your plan is to dynamically add checkboxes by just adding some DOM nodes, then you're not doing it the right way.

Comment: In the first load of the page a group of checkbox is displayed correctly. A select list change the HTML dom and display a part of this group using the same HTML view that render correctly in the first time. But dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox" is not transformed to a type="checkbox" and generate the HTML code listed bellow so the input is displayed as an  input type text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dynamically add DOM nodes, they will not be converted into Dojo widgets (dijit). To become such a widget (dijit), the DOM node needs to be parsed. If you setup your web application to use `parseOnLoad`, it will parse the HTML page automatically when loading the webpage, that's why widgets added this way will work properly.

There are two options:

The first one is by parsing the newly added DOM nodes by yourself using the `dojo/parser` module. You can parse the page again using the `parse()` function, but you can also specify a DOM node which should be parsed. More information about this module can be found at the [API docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/parser) or the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html).

Another way (and I recommend this one), is by programmatically adding the widget in stead of adding just a DOM node and parsing it. You can read more about this at the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/CheckBox.html#programmatic-example).